# js/jquery count rows in tbody

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a simple while loop to count the number of rows in the table #offices, and I have no idea why this isn't working, but the alert keeps returning 0...

html:

```
<table id="offices" class="table table-striped">
    <caption class="text-left">
      <p class="lead">Current List of Offices</p>
    </caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Office Name</th>
            <th>Office abrev.</th>
            <th>Display Order</th>
            <th>Edit</th>
            <!-- TMPL_UNLESS is_agent -->
            <th>Delete</th>
            <!-- /TMPL_UNLESS -->
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <!-- TMPL_LOOP Office_loop -->
    <tr>
        <td><!-- TMPL_VAR office_name --></td>
        <td><!-- TMPL_VAR short_name --></td>
        <td><!-- TMPL_VAR sequence_number ESCAPE=0 --></td>
        <td><a href="/office/edit/<!-- TMPL_VAR office_id -->"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit Office</a></td>
        <!-- TMPL_UNLESS is_agent GLOBAL=1 -->
        <td><a href="/office/delete/<!-- TMPL_VAR office_id -->"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Delete Office</a></td>
        <!-- /TMPL_UNLESS -->
    </tr>
    <!-- /TMPL_LOOP -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

js/jquery:

```
var rowCount = $("#offices > tr").length;
alert(rowCount);
var i = 0;
while ( ++i <= rowCount ) {
    console.log( "counting rows: " + i );
}
```

Comment: Use `$("#offices tr")`

Comment: @Satpal i need to target the tbody tr specifically so i dont count the thead rows.

Comment: put it in (document).ready still notta

Comment: Then use `$("#offices > tbody > tr")`

Answer (score 11):

Try with this:

```
$('#tabId tbody').find('tr').length;
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use

```
var rowCount = $('#tableId tr').length;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `$("#offices tbody tr")` instead of `$("#offices > tr")`

`>` is a looks for immediate children.

Comment: yea $("#offices tbody tr") worked.